# How to add new Mapping classes to hibernate running application

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, java-8, bytecode

I would like to add more mapping entities at runtime in hibernate.

Is that possible?

I know hibernate itself does not support that. But what options do I have? I know it is possible to add byte codes at runtime. I am also aware of using the invokedynamic from Java 8.

Comment: What is your exact use-case? Are you trying to add new entities through some plugin mechanism?

Comment: You might try looking at the Envers source code.  I'm pretty sure that they add dynamic classes to Hibernate to manage the auditing tables.